# Send 2 e-mails with mail()

Tags: php, email

I'm trying to send 2 e-mails to different addresses and different subjects.

```
$to = 'contact@example.com';
        $from    = $_POST['email'];
        $subject = 'Contact - '.$_POST['subject'];
        $message = utf8_decode($_POST['msg'])."\r\n";
        $message .= "\r\n-------";
        $message .= "\r\nPhone: ".$_POST['tel']." - E-mail: ".$_POST['email'];
        $headers = 'From:'.$_POST['email']. "\r\n" .
        'Reply-To:'.$_POST['email']. "\r\n" .
        'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();



        $headers2 = "From: Company <noreply@example.com>\n";
        $headers2 .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
        $headers2 .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";

        $message2 = "<html><body>
        Thanks for your contact!</body></html>
        ";
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers); 
mail($from, "Thanks for your contact!", $message2, $headers2);
```

But only the last one it's working. What's wrong? Thanks!

Comment: `CrystalBall.exe has stopped working.` Have you checked for errors or log messages?

Comment: And by the way, what's CrystalBall.exe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My first guess is that you're sending an email to "noreply@example.com" which will surely won't work. Unless I'm mistaken, it should work if `$to` is a valid email address.

## edit

Alright, then check this out, not really a direct answer to the first problem. But I'd consider using something like this: https://github.com/Synchro/PHPMailer

Unless you have a good reason to reimplement a mailing module, I'd try not to reimplement it if someone already did it great. The mailing rfc can be somewhat complicated because it depends on so many rfcs... That said, using a proven solution might solve many more problems than trying to roll your own.

Comment: That's a example. I changed my question for more understanding.

Answer (score -1):

set the $to to go to 2 email addresses

```
$to = 'noreply@example.com,'.$from;
```

Answer (score -3):

```
$headers2 = "From: Company <example@example.com>\r\n";
```

add the '\r' at the end. But that is for the second email(?).